# 2D-float array values scan

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point

I wrote a code by using C language as follows:

```
main()
{
    float x[10][10];  int i,j;   clrscr();
    scanf("%d%d",&i,&j);
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            scanf("%f",&x[i][j]);
 ......
}
```

When i run this program, there is an ABNORMAL TERMINATION  with the
error like 'FLOATING POINT CONVERSIONS NOT LINKED'.
Would you mind tell me what i have mistaken ?

my OS: Windows XP   Compiler:  TurboC

Comment: If you put four spaces in front of both of those lines, it will format them as code and make it much easier to read, I suggest you do that.

Answer (score 6):

http://c-faq.com/fp/fpnotlinked.html

> Some compilers for small machines, including Turbo C (and Ritchie's original PDP-11 compiler), leave out certain floating point support if it looks like it will not be needed. In particular, the non-floating-point versions of printf and scanf save space by not including code to handle %e, %f, and %g. It happens that Borland's heuristics for determining whether the program uses floating point are insufficient, and the programmer must sometimes insert a dummy call to a floating-point library function (such as sqrt; any will do) to force loading of floating-point support. (See the comp.os.msdos.programmer FAQ list for more information.)
>   A partially-related problem, resulting in a similar error message (perhaps ``floating point not loaded'') can apparently occur under some MS-DOS compilers when an incorrect variant of the floating-point library is linked. Check your compiler manual's description of the various floating-point libraries.

Comment: Wow, if that's not a candidate for the DailyWTF, I don't know what is.